# Exception thrown when trying to remove pivot item (with header template) from code behind windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, pivotitem

In my app I need to add and remove pivot items dynamically. I implemented it successfully. But later when I tried to change the pivot items header template, the same code is throwing exception.

The xaml code is as follows

```
 <phone:Pivot x:Name="HeadPivot" Title="SDPOnDemand">
        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="RequestsPI">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Requests" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="FiltersPI">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Filters" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>

        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="SearchPI">
            <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Search Items" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
                </Grid>
            </phone:PivotItem.Header>

        </phone:PivotItem>


    </phone:Pivot>
```

i use the following code to remove and add the pivot Items

```
HeadPivot.Items.Remove(FiltersPI);
HeadPivot.Items.Add(SearchPI);
```

The following exception is thrown in the first line

```
-       $exception  {System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

If I remove the header template it's working fine. May I know if I'm doing anything wrong?

Are this cannot be done ?

Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `Header="Requests"` (and so on) work for you? I mean, do you really want to change the template or just the value?

Comment: The main problem for me is the size of the header when i use the default template. I want to reduce the size that's why I'm using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the default HeaderTemplate does not expect UI elements in the Header.

The way to change how the header looks is by changing the HeaderTemplate property of the Pivot itself, and then assign the appropriate object (most likely a simple string) to the Header property of the PivotItem(s). Something like this:

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="HeadPivot" Title="SDPOnDemand">
        <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="RequestsPI" Header="Requests">
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="FiltersPI" Header="Filters">
        </phone:PivotItem>

        <phone:PivotItem x:Name="SearchPI" Header="Search Items">
        </phone:PivotItem>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

Comment: Thanks it is working fine now. Although this seems like a bug which needs to be reported.

Comment: @Presse The only problem I see is that the error doesn't tell you all that much about the problem. Otherwise - it's rarely needed to have different-looking headers, so putting the template in one place seems okay. Of course, if you want to, you can put a ContentPresenter or ContentControl in the template and then you'll be able to set whatever UI you want for every PivotItem (just as you did in the XAML in the question). :)